# Signed jar blocked from running by java security

Tags: java, jar, jnlp, code-signing-certificate

I've been quite happily signing my jar files for a year or so and had no issues whatsoever, but very recently I have noticed that I'm getting the warning below.

[image: Java Security Warning]

Now, nothing has changed, I'm not creating anything different, my certificate is valid, I'm signing in exact same way, same JDK and same JRE and I'm uploading to the same location and so on so kind of hitting a wall.

I've tried running from a different computer, different OS and JRE, all with same outcome.

What I have also noted though and find this particularly strange, is that even if I add a site exception, I still get the same error.

**Are there any logs or can such logging be enabled to find out exactly why the applications are not being allowed to run?**

Comment: Do you selfsign your jars or do you have an official certificate? Regarding the JDK are you certain, that no other JRE is installed on the system?

Comment: @Lonzak Issue resolved, have since edited post with reason, solution.

In response to your question however, jar was signed with proper certificate.

I think my main stumbling block with these types of issues is knowing where to look and if there were perhaps logs somewhere that gave "journeymen" like me a fair chance of self fault finding, it would make life so much easier :)

Answer (score 1):

My issue was caused by mismatched information in the manifest file inside the jar and the jnlp file, my own oversight as it happens. The CODEBASE and PERMISSIONS differed, not quite sure how that happened but guess it makes sense for java security to not allow such an application to run with said differing information.

Comment: Did you find any logs that helped you figure out the problem? If so that would be useful to note as well.

Comment: I didn't, was just checking everything and came across a different codebase in the manifest file when compared to the jnlp file, which was in part my doing as I had moved the application to another host. If I recall correctly, the permissions in the manifest file also did not match that in the jnlp file and while I'm unsure if these issues alone can cause this problem, rectifying resolved in this instance and has been fine for many months.

I would add though, that I've recently again seen the same issue and the codebases do match, so something else must be causing it this time around.